# Transaction check error while installing GUI in CentOS 7

Tags: user-interface, centos, centos7

I'm getting the following error after running the install gnome command i.e. `yum groupinstall "GNOME Desktop" "Graphical Administration Tools"`
How can I resolve this error?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the error, just in case anyone else go through same error, following are the steps need to be followed,

1. yum upgrade lvm2
2. yum groupinstall "GNOME Desktop"